# How do you handle long runtime updates needed in hook_install()?

Tags: 6, drush, installation

I have a new module that includes a series of [`hook_update_N()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!install.php/function/hook_update_N/6) implementations. I had written these without knowing a module is installed, `hook_update_N()` isn't invoked.

Several of the `hook_update_N()` implementations take advantage of `$sandbox` parameter, as they are lengthy database changes. As far as I know batch API isn't supported in `hook_install()`.

What are my options to run these during module installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to not make it automatic on install. Provide a page from where an admin can launch the batch job.

However, if it absolutely must be automated, I have a suggestion, albeit somewhat crude.

```php
function mymodule_init() {
  $run_batch = variable_get('NOT_INSTALLED_YET', FALSE);
  if ($run_batch) {
    // Redirect to batch launch, or possible just set an approprite message.
  }
}

function mymodule_install() {
  variable_set('NOT_INSTALLED_YET', TRUE);
}
```